# Multiplying every character of a string by three

Tags: python

I want to "multiply" every character of the string `x` three times (such that it occurs three consecutive times).

```
def triple(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        trip = ''
        y = ''
        trip = x[i] *3
        y += trip
    print(y)
```

Currently it is only printing the last character multiplied 3 times

Comment: That's because the `print` statement is outside the for loop.  If you want it to print every time through the loop, indent the `print` statement so it is inside the loop.

Comment: You reset `y` each time.

Comment: @roganjosh: it is in the title.

Comment: @jpeerd499: can you check that the edit matches semantically your question?

Comment: thanks you for the help didnt expect to get such a quick response my first time asking a question

Answer (score 3):

That is because you reset `y` each time to `''` in the loop. So you can solve this with:

```
def triple(x):
    y = ''  # initialize y only at the *start* of the loop
    for i in range(len(x)):
        trip = x[i] *3
        y += trip
    print(y)
```

But it will still be inelegant and a bit inefficient. We can do beter by using a generator or list comprehension, like:

```
def triple(x):
    print(''.join(c for c in x for _ in range(3)))
```

or by using *list comprehension*:

```
def triple(x):
    print(''.join([c for c in x for _ in range(3))])
```

What we do here is iterate over the characters `c` of `x`. For every such character, we iterate three times (by using `for _ in range(3)`). We yield thus every `c` three times after each other. We then join these characters together.

We can also add the characters `c` together in the yield or multiply these, like:

```
def triple(x):
    print(''.join([c+c+c for c in x])
```

or:

```
def triple(x):
    print(''.join([3*c for c in x])
```

Comment: thanks for the help but for some reason my teacher doesnt allow us to use anything that he hasnt taught us so using methods that will do the task better isnt allowed for some reason

Comment: No double loop needed if you do `c+c+c for c in..` (although your method works better for an even more generalized function `repeatchar(text,count)` :)

Comment: @usr2564301: or `c*3`. I know. I was trying to make it a bit educational to show how one can nest loops in list comprehension :)

Comment: @jpreed499: but you did not mention any retraints in your question.

Comment: @usr2564301: well there can be also drawbacks. For instance the amount of memory that is used to construct the string. By using `c+c+c`, or `c*3`, we can eventually need twice the amount of memory than using the nested for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Within your *list comprehension*, simply multiply your string with the number you want to repeat it with, and then join it back again to create your desired string as:

```
>>> my_str = 'ABC'

>>> ''.join([x*3 for x in my_str])
'AAABBBCCC'
```